# Cannot Access the Rescue Admiral Korlis Mission

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have the rescue Admiral Korlis mission on my list but the game won't let e land on Rannoch and I no longer see the target showing where to land on planet. I have defeated the Geth and destroyed the Reaper.  I chose to save the Quarian, not the Geth.  Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Have you completed Priority: Rannoch? If so, you're out of luck. Load a save from before you started the priority mission.

Comment: @Ampersand Defeating the Reaper is the end of Priority: Rannoch. You should post an answer. =P

Comment: It's like my eyes skipped from middle of line 2 to middle of line 3 xD

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do the mission once you have taken back Rannoch for the Priority:Rannoch mission.